# Searching if String differs by one character

Tags: java, if-statement, for-loop

I'm trying to determine if a word entered differs by one character in a text file. I have code that works, but unfortunately only for words that are two characters or less which obviously isn't very useful, and the code itself looks a bit messy. Here's what I have so far:

```
if(random.length() == word.length()){
  for(int i = 0; i < random.length(); i++){
    if( (word.charAt(i) == random.charAt(i))){
      str += word+"\n"; 
      count++;
    }
  }
 }
```

With `random` being the word that was entered by the user, and `word` being the word to search for in the text file.

If I changed my second `if` statement to something along the lines of

```
if( (word.charAt(i) == random.charAt(i)) && (word.charAt(i -1) == random.charAt(i-1)))
```

and if I change `int i` to be = 1 instead, I seem to get more of what I'm looking to accomplish, but then my code is searching for only if the first two letters are the same and not if the last two are as well, which it should be doing.

Comment: So what exactly are you asking?

Comment: Given a word by a user, in this case `random`, I'm trying to search a text file which has a large amount of words and see if any of the words in this text file differ by only one character of `random`. For instance; day is similiar to words : say, ray, dam, dab etc...

Comment: What do you mean by `one changed character`? One deletion, one insertion or just one edit?

Comment: @marc, just one edited character. `Word` would still have to be the same length as `random` so no deletion or insertion, but it could differ by any singular character value.

Comment: I like this line `str += word+"\n";`. It looks so useful to have the String in `word` as many times as the its length combined in a single String.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I assume you need a function like this? I just wrote and tested it.

```
static boolean equals(String word1, String word2, int mistakesAllowed) {
    if(word1.equals(word2)) // if word1 equals word2, we can always return true
        return true;

    if(word1.length() == word2.length()) { // if word1 is as long as word 2
        for(int i = 0; i < word1.length(); i++) { // go from first to last character index the words
            if(word1.charAt(i) != word2.charAt(i)) { // if this character from word 1 does not equal the character from word 2
                mistakesAllowed--; // reduce one mistake allowed
                if(mistakesAllowed < 0) { // and if you have more mistakes than allowed
                    return false; // return false
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: I've been trying to incorporate your example to suit mine, but unfortunately, I can't get it to work. What is the `int mistakesAllowed`?

Comment: it is the number of different characters that are allowed between word1 and word2, so in your case it should be 1. I'll edit the code a bit for you to understand.

Comment: Okay, thanks, that's what I thought. I think my problem is that your example returns a boolean, and since I'm using a text file, I have to write inputFile.close() after each true/false statement, and therefore this method is returning my word as false and not printing.

Comment: Well, then print it when it returns true! Something like `if(equals(word, random, 1) == true) str += word+"\n";`

Comment: Thank you very much @luuksen, your answer definitely makes sense to me now because of your in-depth answer and comments. I'm trying to change one line though: if(mistakesAllowed > 0){   str += word+"\n";count++;}, 
but it doesn't seem to work. I'll keep trying though!

Comment: Keep in mind that I posted a `static` method. `static` methods can't access variables outside of that method, for example your `str`. Don't try to change `str` inside of the method, but in your `main()` like I posted in my `if()` above. Or you can remove the `static` and then you can access the `str` directly. Hope this helps!

Comment: With a bit of adjustment this works well in JavaScript too. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems to be working to me, you just may be interpreting its results incorrectly.

This may be more obvious:

```
int count = 0;     if(random.length() == word.length()) {
for(int i = 0; i < random.length(); i++)
{
    if( (word.charAt(i) != random.charAt(i) ))
    {
        if(count == 0)
        {
            System.out.println("Found first difference!");
        }
        if(count != 0)
        {
            System.out.println("Strings are more than one letter different!");
        }
        count++;
    }
} }
```

If you want to check Strings of different lengths, you'll need to delete characters from the longer one until it's the same size as the shorter.
For example:
If String1 = "abc";
and String2 = "zzzabcdef";

You'll need to delete 6 characters from the second string and test for every combination of 6 characters deleted. So you would want to test the strings: def, cde, abc, zab, zza, zzz, zzb, zzc, zzd, zze, zzf, zaf, zae, zad, zac, zab, zza, zzf, zze, ..., ..., on and on, the list is of size 9 choose 6, so it's definitely not optimal or recommended.

You can however, check to see if a string which is one character longer than the other is just the other string with one added letter. To do this, you want a for loop to grab two substring from 0 to i, and from i+1 to the end. This will leave out the ith character, and looping for the size of the string - 1, will give you first the full string, then the string without the first letter, then missing the second letter, and so on. Then test that substring in the same fashion we did above.

Comment if this was not what you're looking for.

***EDIT***

To see how many words in a file are one letter different than a variable word, you need to loop through the file, getting each word. Then testing if that was string was one letter off. It would be something like this:

```html
String testAgainst = "lookingForWordsOneLetterDifferentThanThisString";
int words = 0;

Scanner scan = new Scanner(fileName);

while(scan.hasNext())
{
    String word = scan.next();
 
    if( isOneDifferent(word, testAgainst) )
    {
        words++;
    }

    System.out.println("Number of words one letter different: " + words);
}

public boolean isOneDifferent(String word, String testAgainst)
{
    if(word.length() != testAgainst.length())
    {
        return false;
    }

    int diffs = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++)
    {
        if(word.charAt(i) != testAgainst.charAt(i))
        {
            diffs++;
        }
  
        if(diffs > 1)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    if(diffs == 1)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you, could you explain why though count would be equal to 0? I was using count to determine how many words only differed by one letter, so if `count==0`, and you print that you found first difference, that doesn't really make sense to me.

Comment: Oh I see, I thought you were using it to see how many letters were different in a word. I'll change my code to represent what you want.