# in Java script Given two strings, find if they are one edit away from each other

Tags: javascript

can you help me to write a function in javascript to Given two strings, find if they are one edit away from each other example :
(pale, ple ) true
(pales, pale ) true
(pale, bale ) true
(pale, bake) false
(face, facts ) false

Comment: Check this out- [Searching if String differs by one character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27195890/searching-if-string-differs-by-one-character)

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this function to check that string only differs by one edit.

```
function checkDifferntString(str1, str2) {
    let diff = 0;
  if (str1 === str2) return true;                    // equal return true
  let lengthDiff = Math.abs(str1.length - str2.length)
  if (lengthDiff > 1) return false;                  // checks length diff if > 2 return false

  for (let i=0; (i<str1.length || i < str2.length);i++) {
    if (diff > 1) return false;                     // diff greater than 1 return false
    if (str1.charAt(i) !== str2.charAt(i)) diff++
  }
  if (diff <= 1) return true
  else return false;
}

console.log(checkDifferntString("pale", "pale"))   // true
console.log(checkDifferntString("pale", "pales"))  // true
console.log(checkDifferntString("pales", "pale"))  // true
console.log(checkDifferntString("pales", "bale"))  // false
```

I hope it helps. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Check this out.

I made a simple function that iterates through the given two strings and check if there's more than 1 difference (in terms of characters) between these strings, an optional argument `cs` to allow case sensitivity, by default it equals to `false`, so 'a' and 'A' are the same.

```
    function isEditFrom(str1, str2, cs) {
        var cs = cs || false, i = 0, diff = 2, len1 = str1.length, len2 = str2.length, l = (len1 > len2) ? len1: len2;
        if(len1 !== 0 && len2 !== 0) {
            if(cs === false) {
                str1 = str1.toLowerCase();
                str2 = str2.toLowerCase();
            }
            for(; i < l; i++) {
                if(str1[i] !== str2[i]) {
                    if(--diff === 0) {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            }
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

and now we call that function:

```
isEditFrom('Pale', 'bAle'); // returns True
isEditFrom('Pale', 'bAle', true); // returns False as we set the third argument to true enabling case sensitivity, 'a' != 'A'
isEditFrom('face', 'facts'); // returns False
```